# Create a temporary table in MySQL with an index from a select

Tags: mysql, ddl, temp-tables

I have a stored function where I use temporary tables. For performance reasons, I need an index in that table. Unfortunately, I cannot use `ALTER TABLE` because this causes an implicit commit.

Therefore I'm looking for the syntax to add the `INDEX` for `tempid` during creation. Can anyone be of help?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpLivecheck 
(
    tmpid INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
)
SELECT *
FROM   tblLivecheck_copy
WHERE  tblLivecheck_copy.devId = did;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did find the answer on my own. My problem was, that i use two temporary tables for a join and create the second one out of the first one. But the Index was not copied during creation...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpLivecheck (tmpid INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY    
KEY(tmpid), INDEX(tmpid))
SELECT * FROM tblLivecheck_copy WHERE tblLivecheck_copy.devId = did;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpLiveCheck2 (tmpid INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(tmpid), 
INDEX(tmpid))  
SELECT * FROM tmpLivecheck;
```

... solved my problem.

Greetings...

Answer (score 292):

I wrestled quite a while with the proper syntax for CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SELECT.  Having figured out a few things, I wanted to share the answers with the rest of the community.

Basic information about the statement is available at the following MySQL links:

[CREATE TABLE SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) and [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html).

At times it can be daunting to interpret the spec.  Since most people learn best from examples, I will share how I have created a working statement, and how you can modify it to work for you.

1. **Add multiple indexes**

   This statement shows how to add multiple indexes (note that index names - in lower case - are optional):

   ```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE core.my_tmp_table 
   (INDEX my_index_name (tag, time), UNIQUE my_unique_index_name (order_number))
   SELECT * FROM core.my_big_table
   WHERE my_val = 1
   ```
2. **Add a new primary key**:

   ```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE core.my_tmp_table 
   (PRIMARY KEY my_pkey (order_number),
   INDEX cmpd_key (user_id, time))
   SELECT * FROM core.my_big_table
   ```
3. **Create additional columns**

   You can create a new table with more columns than are specified in the SELECT statement.  Specify the additional column in the table definition.  Columns specified in the table definition and not found in select will be first columns in the new table, followed by the columns inserted by the SELECT statement.

   ```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE core.my_tmp_table 
    (my_new_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    PRIMARY KEY my_pkey (my_new_id), INDEX my_unique_index_name (invoice_number))
    SELECT * FROM core.my_big_table
   ```
4. **Redefining data types for the columns from SELECT**

   You can redefine the data type of a column being SELECTed.  In the example below, column tag is a MEDIUMINT in core.my_big_table and I am redefining it to a BIGINT in core.my_tmp_table.

   ```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE core.my_tmp_table 
    (my_important_column BIGINT,
    my_time DATETIME,  
    INDEX my_unique_index_name (my_important_column) )
    SELECT * FROM core.my_big_table
   ```
5. **Advanced field definitions during create**

   All the usual column definitions are available as when you create a normal table.  Example:

   ```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE core.my_tmp_table 
    (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    value BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 UNIQUE,
    location VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT "NEEDS TO BE SET",
    country CHAR(2) DEFAULT "XX" COMMENT "Two-letter country code",  
    INDEX my_index_name (location))
    ENGINE=MyISAM 
    SELECT * FROM core.my_big_table
   ```

Comment: At risk of sounding like a useless "thanks" comment, i want you to know you saved my booty. I wish i had more to give than just an upvote. Temporary tables with indexes can be joined to circumvent the limitation of a joining a temp table to itself, and it seems in my case the index was essential.

Answer (score 6):

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
[(create_definition,...)]
[table_options]
select_statement
```

Example :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable
(id int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable SELECT id FROM table WHERE xyz;
```

Comment: @solick `PRIMARY KEY` is always indexed.