# Update with Joins taking too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

the below queries return about 80K records:

this `select` only takes about 2 seconds to come back:

```
select fs.fsID
from datFS fs
join datAE t2
on fs.fsID= t2.fsID
join @AllCompletedNotYetDeleted t1
on fs.fsID=t1.fsID
where DateSent < DATEADD(m, -6, GETDATE())
```

while his `update` (with the exact same joins) is taking forever... i have to stop it every time, so it is yet to finish...

```
update fs set fs.testrun = getdate()  
from datFS fs
join datAE t2
on fs.fsID= t2.fsID
join @AllCompletedNotYetDeleted t1
on fs.fsID=t1.fsID
where DateSent < DATEADD(m, -6, GETDATE())
```

what did i do wrong?

Comment: is there an index on the table?

Comment: fsID is the Primary Unique key in datFS

Comment: Add an `order by` clause or `select count(*)` on the first query.  The time to return the first record is not the time to return all of them.

Comment: for performance suggestion you have to provide the explain query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan

Comment: @GordonLinoff - yes, thank you, with the order by, it returned 8K in 1 minute, which is a while... is there anything else i can do to improve performance, even on the select?

Comment: @MadamZuZu - You can add an index on `DateSent` as mentioned in my comments of the first answer.

Comment: To what table does `DateSent` belong?  Besides indexing that, I'd recommend refactoring the table variable as a temp table so that you can create indexes on it and SQL Server can keep statistics of it.

Comment: You need to consider that it is having trouble acquiring locks.  Is datFS a busy table.

Comment: You are joining with a TABLE variable... You should add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to tell to the compiler to recompile and take the number of rows in the TABLE variable into account when constructing the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix ON dbo.datFS (DateSent, fsID)
GO

DECLARE @dt DATETIME = DATEADD(M, -6, GETDATE())

UPDATE fs
SET fs.testrun = GETDATE()
FROM datFS fs
WHERE DateSent < @dt
    AND fs.fsID IN (
        SELECT t1.fsID
        FROM @AllCompletedNotYetDeleted t1
        JOIN datAE t2 ON t1.fsID = t2.fsID 
    )
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @date datetime = getdate()

update fs set fs.testrun = @date 
from datFS fs
join datAE t2
on fs.fsID= t2.fsID
join @AllCompletedNotYetDeleted t1
on fs.fsID=t1.fsID
where DateSent < DATEADD(m, -6, @date)
```

You will be calling the date function only once rather than for each row you update.

Comment: Would it make sense to add an index on DateSent?

Comment: Adding an index would help in this case but it will slow down updates on the DateSent column in the future. I for one am for indexing as more often than not it improves read performance, but its not always the solution as it slows down updates and inserts.

Comment: Then I would suggest what @JonH suggested and if you are using SQL Server management studio you can run an execution plan and see what indexes it recommends.

Comment: getdate() is very very fast

Answer (score 0):

Please run this and post the execution plan
The reason for the top 10 is just to let it get done and eliminate transaction log filling up / slow as a problem
You do **NOT** want to leave the with (nolock) active - this is just to test for lock contention

I trust fsID is PK on datAE ??

Declare fsID as PK on @AllCompletedNotYetDeleted
If that is large even try it as #temp
The query optimizer can do poorly with table variables

Rebuild indexes if they are fragmented

```
update  fs 
set top (10) fs.testrun = getdate()  
from datFS fs with (rowlock)
join datAE t2 with (nolock)
     on fs.fsID = t2.fsID
join @AllCompletedNotYetDeleted t1
     on fs.fsID = t1.fsID
where DateSent < DATEADD(m, -6, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that you want indexes.  For this query:

```
select fs.fsID
from datFS fs join
     datAE t2
     on fs.fsID = t2.fsID join
     @AllCompletedNotYetDeleted t1
     on fs.fsID = t1.fsID
where DateSent < DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE());
```

The best indexes are (probably) `datAE(fsID)` and `@AllCompletedNotYetDeleted(fsID)`.  In SQL Server 2014, you can create an index explicitly on a table variable.  In earlier versions, you can do so implicitly by creating a unique constraint.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886050/sql-server-creating-an-index-on-a-table-variable) is helpful.

An index including `DateSent` might be useful.  However, it is unclear what table the column is in, and the `where` condition might be selecting so many rows that the index would not be used.

Finally, you should also check if you are getting duplicate records in the `select`/`update` -- such duplicates just waste time in an update.