# Add a clustered Index to a user defined table type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing, user-defined-types, clustered-index

I'm trying to add a clustered index to a user defined table type. Not a PK, just a clustered index. I see in the documentation that I cannot add a NON CLUSTERED index to a user defined table type, so sounds like it should be possible, but I can't figure out how.

Note: talking about a user defined table type, not a table variable or temp table

Comment: Please replace the `non-clustered-index` tag with the relevant rdbms tag.

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: @SqlZim version is 2008

Comment: I don't think it's possible to create a non unique index on a user defined table type. However, There is a simple workaround.

Comment: what are you referring to?

Comment: Everything here applies to table types too. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17385085/73226

Comment: Now Im really confused bec the following seems to work... and documentation says you cannot create non-clustered index on UDTable Type: CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TempIdxType] AS TABLE(
 [intColumn] [INT] NULL,
 UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED(intColumn)
)
GO

Comment: You're creating a unique constraint. That is backed up by a nonclustered index. SQL Server 2014 allows you to create indexes not associated with constraints in table types.

Comment: what abt a non unique clustered/non clustered?

Comment: Did you read the link? Doesn't seem like it because the answer is there.

Comment: it's better to say "table variable" rather than "table type"

Comment: @FLICKER they are not the same thing. Though instances of table types are table variables so the both have exactly the same limitations.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I was not aware of such a thing. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @MartinSmith a very good detailed answer. Why not mark as duplicate? (btw, I'm glad to find out the workaround I thoght of was described in your answer)

Comment: @MartinSmith I don't think you're correct. Your link says you can create a Non Unique index on a table variable - try doing that on a table type - does not seem to work. I would not mark this as a duplicate and try to answer the question

Comment: @SOS the answer is specific about versions. That works fine in 2014 table types. http://rextester.com/WPCZ35425. The OP here will need to read th bit specific to their version.

Comment: @MartinSmith ok thx. Personally, I would not mark this as a duplicate. MikeTurner is asking abt table types, and your answer is that the rules of table variable apply to table types too, I would use that as an answer to this question. Question is no way a dupe... But no real diff to me