# IN Memory table create unique nonclustered index

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario. I want my inmemory table column to accept multiple NULL values but when entered something besides NULL, It should be unique. This i kept doing in Disk tables using `CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX`.

ex:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX  [IX_customer_PRN]
ON [dbo].[customer](PRN)
WHERE PRN IS NOT NULL
GO
```

Need suitable alternative in `IN MEMORY` tables.

Comment: is it possible for you to use a temp table in stead of an in memory table ?

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886050/creating-an-index-on-a-table-variable) can help

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/indexes-for-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-2017#code-sample-for-syntax) for in-memory tables, you should be able to achieve what you need by just creating a unique non-clustered index on the table, as below:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[customer]
    ADD CONSTRAINT IX_customer_PRN
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (PRN);  
GO
```

Comment: that is about `memory-optimized` tables. Im not sure that is what the OP means by `in memory table`

Comment: Given that the name of the table is `dbo.customer`, I assumed it wasn't a temp or a variable table.

Comment: I think that name was an example of how he would do it with a regular table. But I could be wrong off course

Comment: I could be wrong as well :) Let's wait for OP's answer.

Comment: I agree on that

Comment: Unique non clustered index will accept one null value in In-memory TABLE.  I want the column to accept multiple null values.  But anything besides null should be unique.

Comment: Younus, we are not sure what you mean by `in memory table`. Do you mean something like `declare @mytable table (id int, ...)` ?

Comment: memory-optimized table.  Sorry for confusion