# Unique constraint on multiple columns in a table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table variable in SQL Server 2016, as shown below.

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE (EmpName VARCHAR(500), DOB DATE, AnnualSalary DECIMAL(10,2))
```

I need to make sure combination of EmpName  and DOB is unique.  Following will NOT work - it will say "Incorrect syntax".

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Temp ON @Employee (EmpName,DOB);
```

Since table variable doesn't allow named constraints, what is the best option to achieve this constraint?

Comment: Of course not.  Putting the salary in a. unique index has nothing to do with the constraint you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That was a typo. I updated the question

Comment: give it an unamed constraint (inline) or a unique index (inline) as here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17385085/73226

Comment: This is an interesting requirement. You acknowledge that you could possibly hire two Martin Smiths but not if they were both born on the same day?

Comment: @AaronBertrand This is a simplified example for easy explanation of the real problem I have. Yes, we cannot hire two people with same name and DOB, in this scenario. :-)

Comment: Ok, for future reference, simplifying your problem often comes at a cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can declare a primary key inline

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE (
    EmpName VARCHAR(500), DOB DATE, AnnualSalary DECIMAL(10,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (EmpName,DOB))
```

Or you can change `PRIMARY KEY` for `UNIQUE` if you want a non-primary key.

You can also declare it as an index and give it a name in SQL Server 2016+:

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE (
    EmpName VARCHAR(500), DOB DATE, AnnualSalary DECIMAL(10,2),
    INDEX ix UNIQUE (EmpName,DOB))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have named constraints on table variables. Instead try:

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE (
                         EmpName VARCHAR(500), 
                         DOB DATE, 
                         AnnualSalary DECIMAL(10,2)
                         UNIQUE (EmpName,DOB)
                        );
```