# INSERT record to SQL table with IDENTITY column

Tags: sql

i have this sql table

```
CREATE TABLE Notes(
    NoteID [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    NoteTitle [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    NoteDescription [nvarchar](4000) NULL
) CONSTRAINT [PK_Notes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    NoteID ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And i want to copy records from a temporary table INCLUDING the NoteID(using sql query)..

this is my script:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Notes OFF

INSERT INTO Notes (NoteID, NoteTitle,NoteDescription)
SELECT NoteID, NoteTitle,NoteDescription from Notes_Temp

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Notes ON
```

with this script, i'm getting an error:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Notes' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

is there other way of insert records to a table with identity column using sql query?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Change the OFF and ON around

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Notes ON

INSERT INTO Notes (NoteID, NoteTitle,NoteDescription)
SELECT NoteID, NoteTitle,NoteDescription from Notes_Temp

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Notes OFF
```

Comment: thanks @astander. when i've tried this, i've got another error: "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

Comment: oops! nevermind my comment, i've done a stupid thing and the error i mentioned was for a different line of my script.. anyway, changing the OFF and ON around did solve my problem, thanks a lot

Comment: What if I want to secure my query upon adding new column in Notes table. It will not copy data of newly created column because it is not mentioned in the query.

Answer (score 9):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Notes ON

INSERT INTO Notes
/*Note the column list is REQUIRED here, not optional*/
(NoteID, NoteTitle,NoteDescription)
SELECT NoteID, NoteTitle,NoteDescription from Notes_Temp

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Notes OFF
```

You're inserting values for NoteId that is an identity column.
You can turn on identity insert on the table like this so that you can specify your own identity values.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you are using SQL Server (you don't say) and have misunderstood the meaning and purpose of [IDENTITY_INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).  In general, you are not allowed to explicitly set the value of an IDENTITY column, but by setting IDENTITY_INSERT to ON for a table you can temporarily permit such inserts.

Comment: hmmm, thanks @oldpro.. i think i have indeed misunderstood the purpose of IDENTITY_INSERT. how shameful.. but again let me try to set it to ON