# SQL SERVER – Table Missing Identity Values – Insertion in GAP

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to insert more row between business_Partner_id = 3522 - 8324 with out delete row grater than 8324.
Business_partner_id is a identity column.

F reference

[image]

Please help

Thanks

Comment: You can insert explicit values into an `IDENTITY` column using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF`. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188059.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT record to SQL table with IDENTITY column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766963/insert-record-to-sql-table-with-identity-column)

Comment: @ChrisPickford , But i have so many row to insert between this. explicit value take to much time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can, if you re-seed the table

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (Business_Partner, RESEED, 3522)
INSERT INTO Business_Partner VALUES(/*Values here, without identity column*/)
```

It will insert values into database starting from `business_Partner_id = 3523`. However, it will raise an error when it will reach 8324, but you can again re-seed the table like above.

Comment: Yes Lali, Thank you, i know with this way we can proceed. but i already have business partner scripts with identity column.