# sql query to insert values to auto increament column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi I want to populate value for Auto increament column when insert value for a table from another table. below is query im using and it throws error

```
create table test12
(
Id int,
name varchar(255),
dept varchar(255)
)

insert into test12 values(1,'f','cs'),(2,'b','cse'),(3,'c','cs'),(4,'d','cse'),(5,'e','cs'),(6,'f',null)

select * from test12                                                            

create table test34
(
seq int identity(1,1) not null,
name varchar(255) not null,
dept varchar(255) default('cs')
)
insert into test34(seq,name,dept) values 
(1,(select name from test12),
(select case when dept='cse' then 'Y' else 'N' end as dept from test12))
```

Please let me what is the mistake

Comment: Your inner queries will not work properly since they are going to retrieve multiple rows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT record to SQL table with IDENTITY column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766963/insert-record-to-sql-table-with-identity-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need not to give values for Identity column, it is auto added, just exclude identity column form insert as:

```
INSERT INTO test34 (name, dept) 
SELECT 
    name,
    CASE WHEN dept = 'cse' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS dept 
FROM test12
```

If you really want to add Identity values manually try below SET statements.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT test34 ON;

INSERT INTO test34 (seq, name, dept) 
SELECT 
    ID
    name,
    CASE WHEN dept = 'cse' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS dept 
FROM test12

SET IDENTITY_INSERT test34 OFF;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn `ON` or `OFF` the `IDENTITY_INSERT`

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT test34 ON

insert into test34(seq,name,dept) values 
(1,(select name from test12),
(select case when dept='cse' then 'Y' else 'N' end as dept from test12))

SET IDENTITY_INSERT test34 OFF
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to insert value for auto increment column automatically it will generate values.

```
insert into test34(name,dept) 
select name, Case when dept='cse' then 'Y' else 'N' end as dept from test12
```