# SQL Server Inserting multiple rows using Triggers

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am loading data from a JSON file to a table "main.jsontable" the trigger job is to insert the data of all different countries from "main.jsontable" into "main.country" table. My problem is that the trigger needs to handle inserting multiple rows my current code is:

```
create or alter trigger main.afterParsing
on main.jsontable 
after insert
as
begin
    declare @country nvarchar(50);

    insert into main.country(countryName)
    values(@country)
end;
```

but I get this error (obviously because triggers can only handle inserting 1 row at a time):

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'countryName', table 'assignment2.main.country'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Does anyone know how I can use the trigger to insert multiple rows?

Thanks

Comment: Why a trigger? Insert the raw data into the table then run another script to move the data. That makes it much easier to cleanse the data, remove dupes, improve performance, etc.

Comment: I wish but it's a task for my school work..

Comment: In that case, Possible duplicate of [Handling multiple rows in SQL Server trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695815/handling-multiple-rows-in-sql-server-trigger)

Comment: I've seen that question but i don't think it will work for me since it's updating the table and not inserting. what i need is to insert new data into the tables and not update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `Inserted` pseudo table, and you need to understand that it can contain **multiple rows** (if your `INSERT` statement inserted more than 1 row at once), and you need to treat that table accordingly, using a proper **set-based** approach.

Try something like this:

```
create or alter trigger main.afterParsing
on main.jsontable 
after insert
as
begin
    insert into main.country(countryName)
        select countryName
        from Inserted
        -- if the data being inserted could have NULL in the
        -- countryName - filter those entries out
        where countryName is not null
end;
```

Comment: Still is giving me the same error. I have tried using cursor maybe you'r familiar with it but still have no clue :/

Comment: @FrankanTabone You guys are using triggers AND cursors for this task? What kind of school do you go to??

Comment: cursors no but yes trigger and tbh yes they do give out some weird tasks

Comment: @FrankanTabone: the error says that you cannot insert `NULL` into that column - is there any chance that your `INSERT` statement is producing `NULL` as `countryName` ?? If so, add a `where countryName IS NOT NULL` to the `SELECT` in the trigger. See my updated answer

Comment: This worked. Thanks I've been trying for hours and had no clue how to solve this.