# Sql server 2008 trigger not working after update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to implement a trigger on a table such that some columns get automatically updated each time a row is updated. I am using the following trigger syntax:

```
create trigger degreedSkillPlan_updated on degreedSkillPlan
after update 
as
if (select trigger_nestlevel() )> 1     return;

    declare @id varchar;

     update degreedSkillPlan set updatedDate = getdate(), lastModifiedDate = getDate() FROM inserted 
WHERE inserted.skillPlanId = skillPlanId; ;
```

but this is not working. I haven't really implemented any trigger before. I have read some tutorials online but I am unable to figure out what is wrong with this. Also, will this work for multiple rows as stated in the accepted answer of >[Handling multiple rows in SQL Server trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695815/handling-multiple-rows-in-sql-server-trigger)

Comment: (1) Explain what the code should do.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: "will this work for multiple rows"; No, if you have multiple rows, what will `@id` be set to?

Comment: I have told the purpose of code in the first line. Also, I don't have any sample data and I don't think that is required.

Comment: @HoneyBadger sorry that was wrong code. I have updated my code according to other answer and it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong on multiple levels:

- `varchar` with no length is bad and usually does the wrong thing.
- Assuming `insert` has only one row is incorrect.
- The body should be in a `begin`/`end` block.

So:

```
create trigger degreedSkillPlan_updated on degreedSkillPlan
after update  as
begin
    if (trigger_nestlevel() ) > 1 return;

    update degreedSkillPlan
        set updatedDate = getdate(),
            lastModifiedDate = getDate()
        where skillPlanId in (select i.skillPlanId from inserted i);
end;
```

Maybe this will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I will accept the answer in 6 mins as SO is not allowing me to do it now.