# SQL Server change column value on insert trigger

Tags: sql-server, oracle, triggers

How do I change values of a column in an insert trigger ? In Oracle I can use the following code to change the col1 value to upper case in an `INSERT Trigger`. How do I do it in SQL Server ?

```
IF exists (select col1 from inserted where col1 is  NOT NULL )
        begin 
            :NEW.col1:= UPPER(:NEW.col1);
        end
```

Comment: Are you using a BEFORE or AFTER trigger?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I edit values of an INSERT in a trigger on SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580123/how-can-i-edit-values-of-an-insert-in-a-trigger-on-sql-server)

Comment: @TabAlleman in sql server there is no such thing as a before trigger.

Comment: Well, ok it's actually called an "INSTEAD OF" trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using an INSTEAD OF trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON MyTable INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
    INSERT MyTable(col1, [other columns])
    SELECT UPPER(i.col1)
        , i.[other columns]
    FROM Inserted i
```