# Trigger converts all other inserted values to null when ran

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

The following trigger I have wrote to, upon insertion of an Operator name in a record, update the SetHours field with data from another table which contains that operators hours. Tis does not live update, which I would like. It updates when the table is next viewed.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[FindOperatorHours]
ON [dbo].[tblTime]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN  
  INSERT tblTime (SetHours)
    SELECT ISNULL(INSERTED.SetHours, tblUser.OperatorHours) AS SetHours
    FROM INSERTED
    JOIN tblUser ON INSERTED.Operator = tblUser.UserID
END
```

This coverts all data apart from SetHours to NULL upon re-open of the table, however the value has been fetched correctly?
Is it possible to get this to live update, and not convert my data to null?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server change column value on insert trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326987/sql-server-change-column-value-on-insert-trigger)

Comment: you need to select all the other columns and include them in your insert statement in the trigger. The INSTEAD OF trigger doesnt insert anything apart from what you do. Or use an after trigger instead and then update the rows that this time have been inserted already

Comment: Thanks Martin - I thought as much, I was mixing up my syntax and is wasn't working, I have now had some success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *inserting* new rows, so you need to include *all* the columns:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[FindOperatorHours]
ON [dbo].[tblTime]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN  
  INSERT tblTime ( . . . , SetHours)
    SELECT . . ., COALESCE(i.SetHours, tblUser.OperatorHours) AS u
    FROM INSERTED i JOIN
         tblUser u
         ON i.Operator = u.UserID;
END;
```

Include all the other columns in the `. . .`.

Comment: This solves my issue, I was forgetting to include the other columns! How would I go about using update?

Comment: @OllieSharratt . . . LOL.  I wrote that before i realized what the problem was.  I've fixed the answer.