# How to handle null while setting date in log4j2 jdbcappender?

Tags: java, jdbc, log4j2, appender

When I set null value in the date column I get "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000" value in my table and I am expecting NULL in that column.
As this is handled properly in jdbc if I put like this

```
preparedStatement.setBindParam(Types.TIMESTAMP, 12, startdate);
```

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">

    <CustomLevels>
        <CustomLevel name="TESTLOG" intLevel="552" />
    </CustomLevels>

    <Appenders>

        <JDBC name="myAppender" tableName="MYTABLE">
            <DataSource jndiName="java:MyDataSource" />
            <Column name="ID" pattern="%X{ID}" isUnicode="false"/>
            <Column name="startdate" pattern="%X{startdate}" isUnicode="false"/>
            <Column name="enddate" pattern="%X{enddate}" isUnicode="false"/>
        </JDBC>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace"  includeLocation="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="myAppender" level="TESTLOG" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Datatype of columns startdate and enddate is **datetime**

```
ThreadContext.put("startdate", startdate != null ? startdate.toString() : null);
ThreadContext.put("enddate", a_reportEndDate != null ? enddate.toString() : null);
final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();
LOGGER.log(Level.forName("TESTLOG", 552), "");
```

The same is for String with null value.

Comment: Maybe your table was created with default values for timestamp columns?

Answer (score 2):

**Inserting null**

I don't think it's possible to get `null` into any column of any type using `JDBCAppender` with patterns like this.

[This thread](http://apache-logging.6191.n7.nabble.com/JDBC-Appender-how-to-have-the-pattern-produce-NULL-td56310.html) popped up a couple of years ago, followed by [this Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1083).  None of it seems to have gotten any attention.

The short version is that a `StringBuilder` is used between pattern and prepared statement, and thus the `INSERT` always gets a non-null string, even if (in your example) `null` is the value in the `ThreadContext`.  So it's possible to insert an empty string, or the string `"null"`, but it doesn't appear to be possible to insert the *value* `null`.

**January 1, 1900**

When I run your example against a MySQL database, the insert fails up front, because MySQL doesn't know how to construct a `DATETIME` from an empty string.

I'm guessing you're using SQL Server, which will happily turn an empty string into `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`, because *of course* that's what you meant.

Regardless of the database you use, `JDBCAppender` is going to fill the `INSERT` statement with non-null strings.  What happens from there will vary from DB to DB.

**Why?**

At first it may seem strange that the framework is changing your value (`null`) to another value (empty string).  However, at its core, logging *is* about strings of text.

Yes, there's an appender that will write these strings to a database.  And yes, your database can in turn coax those strings into types like `DATETIME` or `INTEGER`.  But to any given appender, it's all really just about manipulating and outputting strings.

**Possible work-around**

If you really want to get `null` into the database using `JDBCAppender`, you may be able to [write a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3580473/2999566).

**Final Observation**

Not sure if this helps any, but I may as well present all my findings:

Using `ColumnMapping` instead of `Column` in your log4j config allows you to specify a class name.  The presence (or absence) and value of this class name does change the value that is inserted into the database.  For example, using SQL Server Express 2014:

```
<ColumnMapping name="startdate" pattern="%X{startdate}" type="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
```

Will cause the current date and time to be logged when `startdate` is null, instead of 1900-01-01.  Using `java.sql.Date` instead will log the current date without time.

Comment: Since i am using java 6 and ColumnMapping  is in not supportted in log4j-core-2.3.jar