# How can I store more than one value in stored procedure?

Tags: sql

If I want to store more than one value in a variable how can I do that in stored procedure?

I mean we have array concept in normal programming do we have something like that in stored procedure

Comment: Do you mean something like [csv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)?

Comment: As Luis pointed out, databases use tables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the storage is needed just within the scope of procedure then temp tables are there to rescue you.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your specific database, there are several options available.

In SQL Server, you can define

- a temporary table for just your connection (`CREATE TABLE #YourTable(.....)`)
- a global temporary table visible to any connection (`CREATE TABLE ##YourTable(.....)`)
- a table variable (`DECLARE @YourVariable TABLE (.....)`)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable that is a complete table. Here's a code sample:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(
    EmpID int NOT NULL,
    OldVacationHours int,
    NewVacationHours int,
    ModifiedDate datetime);
UPDATE TOP (10) HumanResources.Employee
SET VacationHours = VacationHours * 1.25,
    ModifiedDate = GETDATE() 
OUTPUT inserted.BusinessEntityID,
       deleted.VacationHours,
       inserted.VacationHours,
       inserted.ModifiedDate
INTO @MyTableVar;
--Display the result set of the table variable.
SELECT EmpID, OldVacationHours, NewVacationHours, ModifiedDate
FROM @MyTableVar;
GO
--Display the result set of the table.
SELECT TOP (10) BusinessEntityID, VacationHours, ModifiedDate
FROM HumanResources.Employee;
GO
```

As you can see you declare it just like a normal table. It will go out of scope at the end of the procedure.

These are called *table variables*. There are also *temporary tables* which you can create, that work in much the same way, expect that you declare them with: `create table #tmp (Col1 int, Col2 int);`

There's a good SO post about the difference between the two here: [What's the difference between a temp table and table variable in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server)

And to go back to your original question: you can create a table variable and pretend it's an array (well it sort of is!). You just have to think in terms of SQL for array functions, so instead of `.Find` you would use a `WHERE` clause.