# sql-server 2008, differences between tables

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

What are the differences between the following 3 in sql-server 2008?

```
#Table_name
##Table_name
@Table_name
```

Comment: http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/yet-another-temp-tables-vs-table-variables-article

Comment: @TimSchmelter That repeats some inaccuracies found elsewhere on the web, the most glaring being the claim that operations on table variables are not logged. I commented to that effect a couple of months ago and my comment was never published. I believe my answer here to be one of the most accurate and comprehensive comparisons. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server/16386#16386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN: Database Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) (reformatted to better suit the question).

Certain symbols at the beginning of an identifier have special meaning in SQL Server.

- **@**: A regular identifier that starts with the at sign always denotes a local variable or parameter and cannot be used as the name of any other type of object.
- **#**: An identifier that starts with a number sign denotes a temporary table or procedure.
- **##**: An identifier that starts with double number signs (##) denotes a global temporary object. Although the number sign or double number sign characters can be used to begin the names of other types of objects, we do not recommend this practice.
- **@@**: Some Transact-SQL functions have names that start with double at signs (@@). To avoid confusion with these functions, you should not use names that start with @@.

Comment: thank you for the detailed and prompt response

Answer (score 0):

See this Question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64891/886591

```
#table = temp table tied to the spid
##table = global temp table
@table = table variable
```

Answer (score 0):

**#table_name -** Local Temp Table

- It exists only for the duration of a user session or the procedure that created the temporary table
- When the user logs off or when the procedure that created the table completes, the local temporary table is lost

**##table_name -** global temporary table

- It exists for the duration of a user session
- When  the last user session that references the table disconnects, 
  the global temporary table is lost

**@Table_name -** table-variable 
- It also exists only for the duration of a user session

`Temp Table and Table Variable` — both are created in TempDB and not in memory