# Insert into table variable is slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a dynamic sql in stored procedure like

```
@sql = 'SELECT a, 
       b, 
       c d 
FROM   table t 
       LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
              ON t.id = t2.id '
```

and then inserting into a table variable

```
Insert into @tblCustomer

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

The insert statement is taking long time to execute. Is there any way i can improve it?

I am using SQL Server 2008

Thanks

Comment: did your table too big ?

Comment: Have you tried researching anything? Do you have indexes? Show us *something*.

Comment: Is this just an example or why do you do this? There is a static SQL select statement that you execute, fetch the results and insert this into a table. Why so complicated?

Comment: why on earth would you be using dynamic sql for that? Dynamic Sql should be avoided if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

though you cannot do much(simple sql query).

try using temp table instead

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
 ID int,
 col2 <datatype>,
 col3 <datatype>)
```

and insert into it

see if it works faster. read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server)

try indexing your database. it should give you visible performance boost.

Comment: I think Select into #temptable will be faster option

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query :

```
@sql = SELECT a, b, c, d 
FROM table t (NOLOCK) LEFT JOIN table2 t2 (NOLOCK) ON t.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems to mee that it is impossible to optimize. The query is straight forward. Temp tables  if used may slow the process even more due to memory use.