# Update 2nd Table Based Upon Rows Updated In First Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `jhead` and `jjops`.  I am updating `jhead` with the following statement:

```
UPDATE jhead h
SET h.jhpcmp = 1
WHERE h.jhpcmp = '0' AND h.jhpqty <= h.jhqtys
```

But now I want to update `jjops` based upon what I updated in `jhead`.  The statement would be like:

```
UPDATE jjops j
SET j.jascmp = 1, japcmp = 1
WHERE (This is where I am stuck)
```

What links the two tables is the following: `h.jhjob = j.jajob`

Is there some way to update both of the tables together?  Should I first update table `jjops` using a join and then update table `jhead` and if so what Join should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to update two tables "at the same time" is to use a transaction. You can use the output clause as one way to pass stuff from one statement to the next. SQL Server also has a special syntax for joining in an update statement (see the second update)

```
Declare @ids table (jhjob int not null) -- replace with correct data type

Begin Transaction

Update 
    jhead
Set 
    jhpcmp = 1
output 
    inserted.jhjob into @ids
Where 
    jhpcmp = '0' And
    jhpqty <= jhqtys

Update 
    jjops
Set
    jascmp = 1,
    japcmp = 1
From
    jjops j
        inner join
    @ids h 
        on j.jajob = h.jhjob

Commit Transaction
```

Comment: What is @ids? Is that a temporary table?

Comment: It's a table variable, it's similar to a temporary table, although they have different semantics - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server