# SQL Server 2005 - Using temporary tables in a multi-user environment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with this procedure. It uses a couple of temporary tables which it drops and recreates. This is causing loads of crashes, and I can only presume that conflicts are arising.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdditionalVisits_SelectByOrigID] 
(
@orig_job_ID int
)
as

if exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME =   'additionalVisitsPodsCnt')
    drop table additionalVisitsPodsCnt;

SELECT     CONVERT(bit, COUNT(PODS.podID)) AS cnt, AdditionalVisits.this_job_id, AdditionalVisits.orig_job_id
INTO            additionalVisitsPodsCnt
FROM         PODS RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  AdditionalVisits ON PODS.jobID = AdditionalVisits.this_job_id
GROUP BY AdditionalVisits.this_job_id, AdditionalVisits.orig_job_id
HAVING      (AdditionalVisits.orig_job_id = @orig_job_ID)

if exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'additionalVisitsPhotosCnt')
drop table additionalVisitsPhotosCnt;

SELECT     CONVERT(bit, COUNT(Photos.photoID)) AS cnt, AdditionalVisits.this_job_id, AdditionalVisits.orig_job_id
INTO            additionalVisitsPhotosCnt
FROM         Photos RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  AdditionalVisits ON Photos.jobID = AdditionalVisits.this_job_id
GROUP BY AdditionalVisits.this_job_id, AdditionalVisits.orig_job_id
HAVING      (AdditionalVisits.orig_job_id = @orig_job_ID)

SELECT     AdditionalVisits.id, AdditionalVisits.this_job_ID, AdditionalVisits.orig_job_ID, AdditionalVisits.reason, AdditionalVisits.date, ThisJob.Job_Reference_No, 
                  ThisJob.Job_POD_Filename, ThisJob.Job_Photo_Filename,    ThisJob.Job_Signed_For_Name, ThisJob.Job_Value, ThisJob.Job_Advance_Payment, 
                  ThisJob.Job_Eoj_Payment, ThisJob.Job_Status, ThisJob.Job_Date_Added, ThisJob.Job_Start_Date, additionalVisitsPhotosCnt.cnt AS Job_Photo_Supplied, 
                  additionalVisitsPodsCnt.cnt AS Job_POD_Supplied
FROM         AdditionalVisits INNER JOIN
                  Jobs AS ThisJob ON AdditionalVisits.this_job_ID = ThisJob.Job_ID    INNER JOIN
                  additionalVisitsPodsCnt ON AdditionalVisits.this_job_ID = additionalVisitsPodsCnt.this_job_id INNER JOIN
                  additionalVisitsPhotosCnt ON AdditionalVisits.this_job_ID = additionalVisitsPhotosCnt.this_job_id
WHERE     (AdditionalVisits.orig_job_ID = @orig_job_ID) AND (ThisJob.Job_Status <> 7)
```

The errors I get are as follow:

```
Cannot drop the table 'additionalVisitsPodsCnt', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. There is already an object named 'additionalVisitsPodsCnt' in the database.
```

or

```
 Invalid object name 'additionalVisitsPhotosCnt'.
```

These errors are intermittent. Sometimes it just works.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Try using actual temporary tables with the `#` prefix in their names.  Like `#additionalVisitsPodsCnt`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if this table is only used from this one procedure, use a "real" [local temporary table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (created in `tempdb`), by prefixing the table name with `#`:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(bit, COUNT(PODS.podID)) AS cnt, 
        AdditionalVisits.this_job_id, AdditionalVisits.orig_job_id
INTO            #additionalVisitsPodsCnt
FROM         PODS ....
```

This way it is isolated from all other sessions, even if concurrent calls to this procedure are made by others.

Comment: Just do a sanity check, however, to make sure that nothing else is dependent on tables `additionalVisitsPodsCnt` and `additionalVisitsPhotosCnt`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the normal pattern I used for a #temp table.  (Notice the "#" prefix).

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TableOne
end


CREATE TABLE #TableOne
( 
SurrogateKey int , 
NameOf varchar(12)
)


/*
Do something with temp table
*/




IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TableOne
end
```

Comment: 1) why do you check if the table exists at the beginning?  If it did, wouldn't that be unexpected, and likely a problem if you are now silently dropping it?  2) isn't the table guaranteed to exist at the end?  So why check for existence before dropping it?

Comment: The code the premature exists, you can sometimes have a #temp table that gets orphaned.  I'm a c# developer.  I check for things ( if null!=someObject {  someObject.DoSomething(); }........ before I use them.   What you don't see in the simple examples is that you could call a nested stored procedure .. and the #temp table is still in scope, so the nest-procedure could drop the #temp table.......thus why I do "checks" before dropping.  It is a style thing I guess, but its how I roll.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using table variables instead.

[This StackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server) explains it better than I would... ;)