# Declaring Temp Table

Tags: sql-server

I am reading stored procedures and reviewing them, I see this declartion in one of the procedures. It seems to me that it is trying to create a Temp Table named @uzovi_nummers. What I am trying to figure out is what is this "uzovi_nummer_n_4". Is it a custom datatype?

```
DECLARE @uzovi_nummers TABLE (
        uzovi_nummer uzovi_nummer_n_4,jaar INT
        )
```

Comment: It's the Column name & datatype I think. ( that's why i placed this in comment )

Comment: Yes, it's a user defined type. And to be precise, it's not a temp table, but table variable (very similar to temp table, but not exactly the same ) .

Comment: Thanks, I just needed the confirmation. Would accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a table variable. A temp table would have a hash in front of it `#temptable`. Anything written in a query with a single `@a` in front will be a variable.

Also there are a fair amount of differences between a temp table and a table variable, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server?rq=1) would be good reading to understand the difference.