# Unresolved reference to an object on a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm changing schemas in my stored procs and I encountered this error for a particular temp table:

> SQL71502: Procedure: [LS1].[Report_ChildPAXData_Summary] has an
>   unresolved reference to object #baggage

The line it is pointing to is below:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#baggage')            IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #baggage
```

Is this a declaration issue? Just want to know how to resolve this error as I will encounter a few more temp tables in other stored procs.

**Update:** As mentioned in comment, posted whole stored proc:

```
/*
    Executed as part of /Support/ChildPAXList report.
*/
CREATE Procedure [LS1].[Report_ChildPAXData_Summary]
      @firstDatetimeToLoad datetime = NULL
     ,@lastDatetimeToLoad datetime  = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempPersonDetail')   IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #tempPersonDetail

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#baggage')            IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #baggage

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FlightsToCheck')     IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #FlightsToCheck

    CREATE TABLE #tempPersonDetail 
    (
        PKCreateDate                datetime,
        Flight_DepartureDateTime    DATETIME,
        FlightNumber                NVARCHAR(50) ,
        Dep_AirportCode             CHAR(3),
        Arr_AirportCode             CHAR(3),
        Person_PersonTypeId         INT,
        person_Name                 varchar(101),   --Forename varchar(50) + '\' char + surname varchar(50)
        TDI_DOB                     DATETIME,
        Person_DOB                  DATETIME,
        TDI_Yr                      INT, 
        Per_yr                      INT, 
        Person_Age                  INT,
        Person_TitleID              INT,
        adult                       BIT NULL,
        child                       BIT NULL,
        infant                      BIT NULL,
        female                      BIT NULL,
        male                        BIT NULL,
    )

    if(@firstDatetimeToLoad is null)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @firstDatetimeToLoad = DATEADD(HOUR,3 , cast(cast(GETDATE()+1 as date) as datetime))  
    END
    if (@lastDatetimeToLoad is null)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @lastDatetimeToLoad = DATEADD(HOUR,27,@firstDatetimeToLoad)  
    END

    --stage people detail 
    INSERT INTO     #tempPersonDetail 
    (PKCreateDate,Flight_DepartureDateTime,FlightNumber,Dep_AirportCode ,Arr_AirportCode,Person_PersonTypeId,person_Name, TDI_DOB, Person_DOB,TDI_Yr,Per_yr,  Person_Age, Person_TitleID,infant, female, male) 

    select      PK.createddate
                ,FLT.DepartureDateTime
                ,FLT.FlightNumber
                ,dep.AirportCode
                ,arr.AirportCode
                ,per.PersonTypeId
                ,per.firstname + '/' + per.surname [person_Name]
                ,TDI.DateOfBirth
                ,per.DateOfBirth
                ,CONVERT( int, FLOOR( DATEDIFF( hour, TDI.DateOfBirth, GETDATE() ) / 8766.0 ) ) AS TDI_Yr --age in years based on TDI table
                ,CONVERT( int, FLOOR( DATEDIFF( hour, per.DateOfBirth, GETDATE() ) / 8766.0 ) ) as Per_yr --age in years based on Person table
                ,per.age
                ,per.TitleID 
                ,case   when per.personTypeid = 3 then 1 --set as infant if persontypeid = 3
                        end 
                ,case   when per.TitleId in (2,3,4) then 1 --set as female depending on title id
                        end
                ,case --set as male depending on title
                        when per.TitleId not in (2,3,4) then 1
                        end

    from            Reservations_Live.dbo.Flight                        flt  
    inner join      Reservations_Live.dbo.FlightReservation             fr  (nolock)    on  fr.FlightId         = flt.FlightId          --and flt.flightnumber = @FlightNumber
    inner join      Reservations_Live.dbo.Product                       p   (nolock)    on  p.ProductId         = fr.Productid  
    inner join      Reservations_Live.dbo.ProductPerson                 pp  (nolock)    on  pp.ProductId        = p.productId  
                                                                    and pp.StatusId         not in (7,8)  
    inner join      Reservations_Live.dbo.Package                       pk              on  p.PackageId         = pk.PackageId
    inner join      Reservations_Live.dbo.Person                        per (nolock)    on  per.PersonId        = pp.PersonId  
    inner join      Reservations_Live.dbo.FlightSector                  sec (nolock)    on  sec.FlightSectorId  = flt.FlightSectorID  
    inner join      Reservations_Live.dbo.Airport                       dep (nolock)    on  dep.AirportID       = sec.DepartureAirportID  
    inner join      Reservations_Live.dbo.Airport                       arr (nolock)    on  arr.AirportID       = sec.ArrivalAirportID  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Reservations_Live.dbo.TravelDocumentInformation TDI             ON (TDI.ProductPersonID = pp.ProductPersonId)
    --inner join    #flightstocheck                 ftc             on cast(flt.departuredatetime as date)  = ftc.FlightDepartureDate
                                                                --  and  flt.flightnumber = ftc.flightnumber
    WHERE           flt.DepartureDateTime   between @firstDatetimeToLoad and @lastDatetimeToLoad  
    and             flt.flightstatusId      <> 6  -- 6 -> cancelled flight  

    --update staged people data to the correct child status
    -- children over 11 to be considered as adult for purposes of fuel calculation
    update #tempPersonDetail
    set child = CASE WHEN Person_PersonTypeId = 2 THEN 
    CASE
            --We first look at DOB in the TDI info
            WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), ISNULL(TDI_DOB, GETDATE()), 103) = CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) THEN
                CASE   --if there is no DOB we than look at the person age                                                    
                        WHEN ISNULL(Person_Age, 0) = 0 THEN      --If the age is not defined
                                CASE 
                                        --This is the case in which we do not have any info 
                                        --to base our decision on so we leave the person type unchanged
                                        WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), ISNULL(Person_DOB, GETDATE()), 103) = CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) THEN 1 --CHILD          
                                        ELSE
                                            CASE   -- If there is no age defined we than try person DOB
                                                    --If the passenger is older than 11 we override the person type to Adult
                                                    WHEN CONVERT( int, FLOOR( DATEDIFF( hour, Person_DOB, GETDATE() ) / 8766.0 ) ) > 11 THEN 0 --ADULT
                                                    --otherwise we leave it as a child
                                                    ELSE 2 --CHILD
                                            END
                                END
                        --If the age is defined                                                    
                        WHEN Person_Age> 11 THEN 0 -- ADULT      --If the passenger is older than 11 we override the person type to Adult                                                  
                        ELSE 1 --CHILD       --otherwise we leave it as a child
                END                                      
            ELSE   --If the DOB is present in TDI
                CASE
                        --If the passenger is older than 11 we override the person type to Adult
                        WHEN CONVERT( int, FLOOR( DATEDIFF( hour, TDI_DOB, GETDATE() ) / 8766.0 ) ) > 11 THEN 0 --ADULT
                        --otherwise we leave it as a child
                        ELSE 1 --CHILD
                END
    END    
END    
    --If the passenger is not a child we leave it's person type unchanged
    --update to be adult if adult person type  (1),  or child type (2) but not set to true (as over 11 years old)
    update #tempPersonDetail
    set adult = 1
    where Person_PersonTypeId = 1 or ( Person_PersonTypeId = 2 and child <> 1)


    --select *, iif((cast(pkcreatedate as date) = cast(person_DOB as date)) and TDI_DOB is null and Person_PersonTypeId = 2, 1, 0 ) [Unreliable] from #tempPersonDetail
    --where child=1
    --order by flight_departuredatetime, flightnumber;

    ;with CTE_FlightData 
    AS
    (
        select *
            ,iif(adult = 1 and male = 1, 1, 0 ) [Adult Male]
            ,iif(adult =1 and female = 1, 1, 0) [Adult Female]
            ,iif((cast(pkcreatedate as date) = cast(person_DOB as date)) and TDI_DOB is null and Person_PersonTypeId = 2 , 1, 0 ) [Unreliable]
        from #tempPersonDetail
    )

    select
         flight_departuredatetime
        ,flightnumber
        ,count(1) [Total PAX]
        ,sum(iif(child = 1, 1,0)) [Children]
        ,sum(iif(infant =1, 1, 0))[Infants]
        ,sum([adult male]) [Adult Male]
        ,sum([adult female]) [Adult Female]
        ,sum([Unreliable]) [Potential Unreliable Children]
    from CTE_FlightData
    group by flight_departuredatetime, flightnumber
    order by flight_departuredatetime, flightnumber
END
```

Comment: Can you post all the code of your stored procedure please ?

Comment: @Thomas Hi Thomas, I have posted the whole stored proc above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use table variable instead on temp table. So you do not need to care about deleting the table because it is a variable :

```
DECLARE @tempPersonDetail  table
(
    PKCreateDate                datetime,
    Flight_DepartureDateTime    DATETIME,
    FlightNumber                NVARCHAR(50) ,
    Dep_AirportCode             CHAR(3),
    Arr_AirportCode             CHAR(3),
    Person_PersonTypeId         INT,
    person_Name                 varchar(101),   --Forename varchar(50) + '\' char + surname varchar(50)
    TDI_DOB                     DATETIME,
    Person_DOB                  DATETIME,
    TDI_Yr                      INT, 
    Per_yr                      INT, 
    Person_Age                  INT,
    Person_TitleID              INT,
    adult                       BIT NULL,
    child                       BIT NULL,
    infant                      BIT NULL,
    female                      BIT NULL,
    male                        BIT NULL,
)
```

See this post for [difference between a temp table and table variable in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server).

Comment: Thank you very much, I can see me being a fool that baggage temp table is never actually called upon at all