# temp tables, go commands,

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing the following code into SQL Server Management Studio

```
DECLARE @tab AS table(ProductID integer, StockCount integer)
INSERT INTO @tab
SELECT ProductID, InStock + OnOrder
FROM Inventory.Product;
GO
SELECT * FROM @tab;
```

When I execute the code, an error occurs. Which of the two following actions could I take to prevent the error from happening?

1

```
Modify the INSERT statement to:
INSERT INTO @tab
SELECT ProductID, InStock
FROM Inventory.Product;
```

2

```
--Remove the GO command
```

3

```
--Use a temporary table named #tab instead of the @tab variable
```

4

```
--Add a second GO command after the final SELECT statement
```

Personally, I think 1 and 2 are correct, but with slight disability issues I'm not confident enough in my answer being 100% correct, if anyone could give any pointers that would certainly help or explain why I may be wrong.

EDIT: THE ERROR I'M GIVEN WHEN I RUN A QUERY IS:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'Inventory.Product'.
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 6
Must declare the table variable "@tab".
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  If the problem is that `@tab` is not declared, then the issue is the `GO` statement.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I've just added the error message I am getting

Comment: The first problem is obvious:  the table is not found.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the error is because a Variable's scope is the transaction in which it is declared.

When you declare a variable as soon as you put the `GO` key word which is a batch separator the variable is not visible after that `GO` keyword.

Anyway these are not the factors which should decide whether to use a Table Variable or a Temp table.

Have a look at this question [`What's the difference between a temp table and table variable in SQL Server`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server) to learn about the differences between the Temp tables and table variables and then decide what is best for you.

Comment: I'm still struggling after reading that post, from my understanding, that suggests I need to add another GO command (4) because there is a batch separator? Furthermore, that I also need should use a #tab because it's stored in tempdb? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: yes the temp tables always and table variables sometimes exist in the tempdb, also why do you think you need to add `GO` in your script ?

Comment: Seems the answer was incorrect, I selected 3 and 4 and the answer was incorrect unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I would say 2 & 3 are correct.  The Go will not allow the variable to carry over to the second query, but you could get around this by using a temporary table instead of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

2 & 3 are correct indeed.

1. Remove the go makes it as a single batch, so @tab var would be
   accessible for second SELECT stmnt
2. If you need though to split it into two batches, then as advised before - make it a table.