# SQL Server procedure with STUFF taking too much time

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a simple query in which I am selecting through `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` and inserting into a temp table.

After that, I am joinig this temp table to the main table to get the desired result based on some parameters, but it is taking too long.

I added a clustered index on the table by which I could get the result of `STUFF` part of the query little faster than earlier but the overall result is still slow.

Here is my code sample:

```
DECLARE @TEMP_ACAusVertarg TABLE
                           (ACAusVertag NVARCHAR(MAX),
                            IKLeistungserbringer INT,
                            Rechnungsnummer NVARCHAR(MAX) 
                           )

INSERT INTO @TEMP_ACAusVertarg (ACAusVertag, IKLeistungserbringer, Rechnungsnummer)
    SELECT 
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + T1.ACAusVertrag
               FROM   DB_DMA.REPORTING.Report_3_1_2_3_RechnungsuebersichtPapier_DTA_Ebene_2_TEMP T1
               WHERE
                   --    Erfassungsart = '1'
                   T1.IKLeistungserbringer = T2.IKLeistungserbringer
                   AND T1.Rechnungsnummer = T2.Rechnungsnummer
               ORDER BY 
                   T2.IKLeistungserbringer, T1.ACAusVertrag
               FOR XML path('')), 1, 1, '') AS ACAusVertrag,
        IKLeistungserbringer, Rechnungsnummer
    FROM 
        DB_DMA.REPORTING.Report_3_1_2_3_RechnungsuebersichtPapier_DTA_Ebene_2_TEMP T2
    WHERE 
        T2.Erfassungsart = 1

    SELECT 
        REPORT.Bundesland,
        REPORT.Regionalkennzeichen,
        REPORT.SGS,
        REPORT.AC,
        ACAUSVERTRAG.ACAusVertag,      --NEW
        REPORT.PNR,
        REPORT.Rechnungsnummer,
        REPORT.Zahldatum,
        REPORT.IKRechnungssteller,
        REPORT.NameRechnungssteller,
        REPORT.StrasseRechnungssteller,
        REPORT.PLZRechnungssteller,
        REPORT.OrtRechnungssteller,
        REPORT.IKLeistungserbringer,
        REPORT.NameLeistungserbringer,
        REPORT.StrasseLeistungserbringer,
        REPORT.PLZLeistungserbringer,
        REPORT.OrtLeistungserbringer,
        SUM(REPORT.AnzahlVerordnungen) AS AnzahlVerordnungen
    FROM 
        DB_DMA.REPORTING.Report_3_1_2_3_RechnungsuebersichtPapier_DTA_Ebene_2_TEMP REPORT WITH (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN 
        @TEMP_ACAusVertarg  AS ACAUSVERTRAG ON ACAUSVERTRAG.IKLeistungserbringer = REPORT.IKLeistungserbringer
    WHERE   
        SGS = @SGS      
        AND AC = @AC
        AND Bundesland = @Bundesland
        AND Regionalkennzeichen = @Regionalkennzeichen
        AND Jahr = @Jahr
        AND Erfassungsart = '1'
    GROUP BY 
        REPORT.Bundesland, REPORT.Regionalkennzeichen,
        REPORT.SGS, REPORT.AC, REPORT.PNR,
        REPORT.Rechnungsnummer, REPORT.Zahldatum,
        REPORT.IKRechnungssteller, REPORT.NameRechnungssteller,
        REPORT.StrasseRechnungssteller, REPORT.PLZRechnungssteller,
        REPORT.OrtRechnungssteller,
        REPORT.IKLeistungserbringer, REPORT.NameLeistungserbringer,
        REPORT.StrasseLeistungserbringer,
        REPORT.PLZLeistungserbringer, REPORT.OrtLeistungserbringer,
        REPORT.Berichtigungsgrund,
        ACAUSVERTRAG.ACAusVertag 
    ORDER BY 
        REPORT.IKLeistungserbringer
```

Parameter values are coming from SSRS Report. Any suggestions please?

Comment: You have two queries there. Have you established which one takes the longest?

Comment: Hey @Nick.McDermaid thanks for quick response.   first part takes only 20 secondes and the second part takes long with join with the TEMP table if i remove the join than it takes only 10 seconds

Comment: First perhaps try a temp table, suitably indexed and see if that helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server

Comment: It's midnight here. I'll see how you're going tomorrow.

Comment: i already have an index on the main table . do you mean temp table for the main table or what?

Comment: ok thanks @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Sorry, try a temp table (#MyTable) instead of a table variable (@MyTable), and concentrate on getting the indexing right. Temp tables can perform better than variables for large datasets.

Comment: Hey @Nick.McDermaid Thanks a lottt for help . it really worked . :)   sorry had Vacations so cpuld not reply early.

Comment: Awesome glad to help. If you have time please explain more detail in an answer for anyone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got the Solution by using the temp Table rather than table variable. And the difference in performance is amazing i got the result in less than 5 seconds instead of 2 minutes.

Here is my code for temp Table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('DB_DMA.REPORTING.Report_3_1_2_3_RechnungsuebersichtPapier_DTA_Ebene_2_TEMPtest')  


IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE DB_DMA.REPORTING.Report_3_1_2_3_RechnungsuebersichtPapier_DTA_Ebene_2_TEMPtest



        SELECT DISTINCT
  STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + T1.ACAusVertrag
          FROM DB_DMA.REPORTING.Report_3_1_2_3_RechnungsuebersichtPapier_DTA_Ebene_2_TEMP T1
          WHERE
           --    Erfassungsart = '1'
             T1.IKLeistungserbringer = T2.IKLeistungserbringer
             AND T1.Rechnungsnummer = T2.Rechnungsnummer

             ORDER BY T2.IKLeistungserbringer,T1.ACAusVertrag
             FOR XML path('')
       ),1,1,'') AS ACAusVertrag,
       IKLeistungserbringer,Rechnungsnummer

       INTO DB_DMA.REPORTING.Report_3_1_2_3_RechnungsuebersichtPapier_DTA_Ebene_2_TEMPtest 

       FROM DB_DMA.REPORTING.Report_3_1_2_3_RechnungsuebersichtPapier_DTA_Ebene_2_TEMP T2
WHERE T2.Erfassungsart = 1
```