# Different Group By based on values in other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have two tables; SalesData and AllOffers.

SalesData table has Brand (can never be null), Product type (can be null), Lot (can never be null), Size of product (can never be null), Stage (can never be null), Province (will be null if Stage = "WIP"), Packed On Date (can never be null) and Quantity (can never be null).

AllOffers table has Province (can never be null), Offer number (can never be null), Product Type (can be null), Brand (can never be null), Product Size (can never be null), Lot (can never be null), Packed on date (can never be null), Quantity (can never be null), and Offer Status (can never be null).

I have an application with two panes. On the left pane, the user creates an "Offer" based on the lots available in SalesData, and the right pane, shows the SalesData table with an additional "Available Quantity" column that is calculated on the fly as the user creates an offer.

The data needs to be grouped by Province, Stage, Product Type, Size, and Packed On date to provide an Available Quantity. I am having trouble grouping my data because of Nulls in Province and Product Type.

This is what I have

```
SELECT
        SalesData.Province,
        SalesData.Stage,
        SalesData.ProdType,
        SalesData.Brand, 
        SalesData.Size,
        SalesData.Lot,
        SalesData.PackedOn,
        SalesData.Qty, 
        CAST(SalesData.Qty AS decimal(12, 0)) - CAST(AllOffersSub.Qty AS decimal(12, 0)) AS Available 
    FROM
        SalesData LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT
                    Province,
                    Brand,
                    Stage,
                    Lot,
                    Size,
                    PackedOn,
                    ProdType, 
                    SUM(CAST(Quantity AS decimal(12, 0))) AS Qty
                FROM
                    AllOffers
                WHERE
                    (OfferStatus = 'Unconfirmed')
                OR  (OfferStatus = 'Confirmed')
                GROUP BY
                    Province,
                    Brand,
                    Stage,
                    Lot,
                    Size,
                    PackedOn,
                    ProdType
        ) AS AllOffersSub ON
        AllOffersSub.Brand = SalesData.Brand
    AND AllOffersSub.Lot = SalesData.Lot
    AND AllOffersSub.Size = SalesData.Size
    AND AllOffersSub.PackedOn = SalesData.PackedOn
    AND AllOffersSub.Stage= SalesData.Stage
    AND CASE
            WHEN SalesData.Province IS NULL THEN 1 
            WHEN AllOfferssub.Province = SalesData.Province THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 END =1 
    AND CASE 
            WHEN SalesData.ProdType IS NULL AND AllOffersSub.ProdType IS NULL THEN 1 
            WHEN AllOfferssub.ProdType = SalesData.ProdType THEN 1  
            ELSE 0  
        END = 1;
```

The problem is that a lot can show up as WIP (work in progress, which means the province=Null) and FG (finished good, which means the province will not be null). For such a lot, the grouping does not take place, and I end up with one lot with same packed on date, Stage, Product Type, Size, showing up as many times as the number of orders pertaining to that lot.

Is there a way to group selectively based on a criterion? For example, if stage = "WIP" then group by  Stage, Product Type, Size, and Packed On date else group by  Stage, Product Type, Size, and Packed On date ?

This is the sample of the Offer table:

```
ID|Customer|OfferNum|Stage|ProdType|Brand|Size|Lot|PackedOn|Quantity|Status
1 |A       | A1     |WIP  | Null   |test |Tst |aaa|1/1/2020|100     |Confirmed
2 |B       | B1     |WIP  | Null   |test |Tst |aaa|1/1/2020|100     |Unconfirmed
3 |C       | C1     |WIP  | Null   |test |Tst |aaa|1/1/2020|100     |Unconfirmed
4 |C       | C1     |FG   | Null   |test |Tst |aaa|1/1/2020|100     |Unconfirmed
```

This is the sample of the SalesData table:

```
ID|Brand|ProdType|Lot|Size|Stage|Customer|PackedOn|Qty
1 |test | Null   |aaa|Tst |WIP  |Null    |1/1/2020|1000
2 |test | Null   |aaa|Tst |FG   |C       |1/1/2020|1000
```

The result of the query is:

```
Customer|Stage|ProdType|Brand|Size|Lot|PackedOn|Qty |Available
Null    |WIP  | Null   |test |Tst |aaa|1/1/2020|1000|900
Null    |WIP  | Null   |test |Tst |aaa|1/1/2020|1000|900
Null    |WIP  | Null   |test |Tst |aaa|1/1/2020|1000|900
C       |FG   | Null   |test |Tst |aaa|1/1/2020|1000|900
```

The result should be:

```
Customer|Stage|ProdType|Brand|Size|Lot|PackedOn|Qty |Available
Null    |WIP  | Null   |test |Tst |aaa|1/1/2020|1000|700
C       |FG   | Null   |test |Tst |aaa|1/1/2020|1000|900
```

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in the ON clause. E.g. `...AND (SalesData.Province IS NULL OR AllOfferssub.Province = SalesData.Province) ...`.

Comment: you will be write two tsql one of them with where condition of `stage = "WIP"` and one of them with `stage != "WIP"` at the end union all both of the queries

Comment: Apologies, but I am extremely new to SQL, so I don't know where I'd put the stage criterion, and how would one do a union of both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes to your query, but the crux of it is that you need to change `province` in your subquery into

```
iif(stage = 'wip', null, province)
```

To avoid duplicating code in both the select statement and the group clause, I put it into a cross apply statement called `ap` and selected from it.

Other than that I just put your subquery into a common table expression, turned your case statements in your `on` clause into `or` statements, and restyled a bit.

```
with modifiedOffers as (

    select      ap.Province, 
                Brand, Stage, Lot, Size, PackedOn, ProdType, 
                Qty = sum(cast(Quantity as decimal(12, 0))) 
    from        @allOffers o
    cross apply (select Province = iif(stage = 'wip', null, province)) ap
    where       o.Status in ('Unconfirmed', 'Confirmed')
    group by    ap.Province, Brand, Stage, Lot, Size, PackedOn, ProdType

)

select      sd.Province, sd.Stage, sd.ProdType, sd.Brand, sd.Size, sd.Lot, sd.PackedOn, sd.Qty, 
            Available = CAST(sd.Qty AS decimal(12, 0)) - o.Qty 
from        @salesData sd
left join   modifiedOffers o  
                on o.Brand = sd.Brand
                and o.Lot = sd.Lot
                and o.Size = sd.Size
                and o.PackedOn = sd.PackedOn
                and o.Stage = sd.Stage
                and (o.Province = sd.Province or sd.Province is null)
                and (o.ProdType = sd.ProdType or sd.ProdType is null and o.ProdType is null);
```

Comment: I had to remove "@" from salesData  and allOffers and it worked after that! Is there an online tutorial I can take that allows me to write queries such as these?

Comment: Tutorials?  Not sure, perhaps [Kahn](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/sql) or [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/).  But as for a place to write and test code, I like [rextester](https://rextester.com/).  [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is also popular.  And then of course there's just doing it in SSMS.  Look into the use of [temp tables and table variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server) if you're worried about polluting your workspace.