# How can I add a where condition on the result of a SQL Server stored procedure without modifying it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I add a `where` condition on the result of a SQL Server stored procedure without modifying it? I have done this method but I have this error, how can I correct it?

```
DECLARE @Colonnes TABLE 
                  (
                      NomColonne NVARCHAR(100),
                      DataType NVARCHAR(100)
                  )

INSERT INTO @Colonnes (NomColonne, DataType)
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'T_RecapElementTechnique'

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'DECLARE @ResultatsTemp TABLE ('

SELECT @query = @query + QUOTENAME(NomColonne) + ' ' + DataType + ',' 
FROM @Colonnes

SET @query = LEFT(@query, LEN(@query) - 1) + ')' 


EXEC sp_executesql @query

INSERT INTO @ResultatsTemp
EXEC adcvie.ChargerRecapElementsTechniques 15

-- Sélectionner les données de la table temporaire
SELECT * FROM @ResultatsTemp where EstVie=1
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 1087, Niveau 15, État 2, Ligne 23
> Must declare the table variable "@ResultatsTemp".
>
> Msg 1087, Niveau 15, État 2, Ligne 27
> Must declare the table variable "@ResultatsTemp".

Comment: This is not great code. Data_type doesn't contain length, so your strings will be at most 30 chars, because it returns just (N)VARCHAR. But i guess i give you +1 for using QUOTENAME

Comment: I suggest you use a temp table instead of a table variable. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server#:~:text=A%20table%20var%20can%20only,procedures%20and%20nested%20dynamic%20SQL.)

Answer (score 2):

Table variables and temp tables created in dynamic SQL are destroyed when the dynamic SQL batch ends.

So either hard-code the table variable DECLARE in the stored procedure body, or add the

```
. . .
set @query = @query + '
INSERT INTO @ResultatsTemp
EXEC adcvie.ChargerRecapElementsTechniques 15

-- Sélectionner les données de la table temporaire
SELECT * FROM @ResultatsTemp where EstVie=1
'

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

to the dynamic SQL.

Comment: I can't hard-code the variables because I have more than 80 variables, do you have a solution please?

Comment: "I can't hard-code the variables because I have more than 80 variables"  Of course you can.  You use the logic you have to generate the SQL, and then paste it into the stored procedure body.

The alternative, as I said, is to add the rest of the logic to the dynamic SQL batch you are building.

Comment: how can i add exactly the logic in sql dynamiqye as i didn't manage to add it ?

Answer (score 1):

Variables don't cross the executesql scope.  However using the select ... into #temptable query you can actually remove the need for the executesql entirely.

So your code would look like this

```
select top 0 * 
into #ResultatsTemp
from T_RecapElementTechnique

insert into #ResultatsTemp
exec adcvie.ChargerRecapElementsTechniques 15

SELECT * FROM #ResultatsTemp where EstVie=1
Drop table #ResultatsTemp
```

The select into creates a new table with the same columns and datatypes so you don't have to worry about varchars and such.
-----Edit-----
Thought of another way to do this with a variable.

Take the declaration out of the dynamic sql and then, in your dynamic sql do

```
SELECT @query = @query + 'alter table @ResultatsTemp 
add column QUOTENAME(NomColonne) + ' ' + 
case when datatype like '%varchar' then datatype + '(max)' 
else datatype end + ';'
from @Colonnes
```

I can't try this right now but I think it will work. You may need to add a dummy column when declaring the table in the first place and then you can drop it after you add all the other ones.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use # because I'm going to use this request in SSRS (sql reporting server), so I have to keep the @.

Comment: Alternatively you can filter the Dataset after it's returned to SSRS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/add-a-filter-to-a-dataset-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Filtering after it is returned like David said above is probably the  only way out.  

If you can create new stored procs you could place the code with the temp table in a stored proc and call that from ssrs.